# Count distinct sets between two columns, while using agg function Pyspark Spark Session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get the number of unique connections between locations, so a->b and b->a, should count as one. The dataframe contains timestamps and start&end location name. The result should present unique connections between stations per day of the year.

[image]

```
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/[user_name]/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2')
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, countDistinct, struct, col
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('cluster1').getOrCreate()

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DateType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
data2 = [
    ('2017-12-29 16:57:39.6540','2017-12-29 16:57:39.6540',"A","B"),
    ("2017-12-29 16:57:39.6540","2017-12-29 17:57:39.6540","B","A"),
    ("2017-12-29 16:57:39.6540","2017-12-29 19:57:39.6540","B","A"),
    ("2017-12-30 16:57:39.6540","2017-12-30 16:57:39.6540","C","A"),
    ("2017-12-30 16:57:39.6540","2017-12-30 17:57:39.6540","B","F"),
    ("2017-12-31 16:57:39.6540","2017-12-31 16:57:39.6540","C","A"),
    ("2017-12-31 16:57:39.6540","2017-12-31 17:57:39.6540","A","C"),
    ("2017-12-31 16:57:39.6540","2017-12-31 17:57:39.6540","B","C"),
    ("2017-12-31 16:57:39.6540","2017-12-31 17:57:39.6540","A","B"),
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("start",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("end",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("start_loc",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("end_loc", StringType(), True)
  ])
 
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df2 = df2.withColumn("start_timestamp",to_timestamp("start"))
df2 = df2.withColumn("end_timestamp",to_timestamp("end"))
df2 = df2.drop("start", "end")
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(truncate=False)

df2_agg = df2.withColumn("date", date_format('start_timestamp', 'D'))\
.groupBy('date', 'start_loc','end_loc').agg(
    collect_list(struct(col('start_loc'), col('end_loc'))).alias("n_routes_sets"),
)
df2_agg.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

,but the Result should be like this:

| date | n_routes |
| --- | --- |
| 365 | 3 |
| 364 | 2 |
| 363 | 1 |

Below line is wrong.

```
collect_list(struct(col('start_loc'), col('end_loc'))).alias("n_routes_sets"),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your lines as per below and reorder the a,b and b,a always as a,b or vice-versa:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, countDistinct, collect_set, struct, col, when, size

...
...
df2 = df2.withColumn("sl2", when(df2['end_loc'] < df2['start_loc'],  df2['end_loc']).otherwise(df2['start_loc']) )
df2 = df2.withColumn("el2", when(df2['end_loc'] > df2['start_loc'],  df2['end_loc']).otherwise(df2['start_loc']) )
df2 = df2.drop("start_loc", "end_loc")

df2.printSchema()
df2.show(truncate=False)

df2_agg = df2.withColumn("date", date_format('start_timestamp', 'D'))\
.groupBy('date').agg(collect_set(struct(col('sl2'), col('el2'))).alias("n_routes_sets"),
) 

df2_agg.select("date", size("n_routes_sets")).show()
```

returns:

```
+----+-------------------+
|date|size(n_routes_sets)|
+----+-------------------+
| 363|                  1|
| 364|                  2|
| 365|                  3|
+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: True, probably I was missing some import due to the fact that it is MRE, but it is not the answer to my problem.

Comment: I tried it on a databricvks notebook your original and it failed and when I added those it worked.

Comment: added the output.

Comment: modded the answer.

Comment: It is a very good answer for this particular MRE, but I am not able to make such a data preprocessing before the agg on my own task. If there would be a way to omit this preprocessing and include filtering the data inside agg, it would be a better answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713355/how-to-filter-rows-for-a-specific-aggregate-with-spark-sql  that may work, but u need collect_set.